# Ruby on Rails. Model Associations

Tags: excel, ruby-on-rails-4, import, associations

I have one Model , `file.rb`, a controller,`filecontroller.rb`, and a set of views for a table called `files`. This was done in order to be able to upload Excel files so that I can view a list in the index view of when someone uploaded an Excel file, the time of its creation and the name of the individual who uploaded the Excel file.

Now, I have another Model, `bottle.rb`, a controller, `bottlecontroller.rb`, and a set of views for a table in the database called `bottles`. The columns in the bottles table in the database are the same as the Excel files.

I already have the ability to upload excel files after some validations so that they can go into the `files` table in the database. And I also followed the rails cast tutorial to be able to import an excel file from the bottle index view and update my `bottles` table.

However, I would like to be able to upload an Excel file and import the information in the file index view. But the import needs to also update the information in the bottles table. So in other words, the Excel import from the file index view needs to be able to update the bottle table database.

I know I need an association between my `files.rb` model and `bottles.rb` model.. but any help would be awesome!

************Updated Question*****************************************

In my `filecontroller.rb`, I have added `@file.bottles =  Bottle.import(params[:file_url])` in the create method after save. I am storing the excel files in`:file_url`. I also added an association in my `file.rb` model of `has_many :bottles`

```
 def create
    .........
    ..........
    if file.save
    @file.bottles =  Bottle.import(params[:file_url])
    end
end
```

And in my bottle model `bottle.rb` I have

```
def self.import(file_url)
    spreadsheet =  Roo::Excel.new(file_url.path, packed:nil,file_warning: :ignore)
    .........
    bottle.save!
end
```

But I am getting a undefined method `path' for nil:NilClas error in this line`spreadsheet =  Roo::Excel.new(file_url.path, packed: nil,file_warning: :ignore)`  It's not recognizing file_url as the path for the Excel file.

Comment: Have you looked at http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html?

Comment: @mysmallidea Thanks for the link! I have looked at the guide but I am not certain how to  import data from excel files from the index file view which is associated with its own pair of controllers/model into the bottles table which has its own views/controller and model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

two ways: either do it in the controller or use a callback in your model.

If you only need to do this action when the user imports from a specific view, you can handle it within the controller.  For example, if uploading the excel file in your index file view calls the 'create' action in files_controller.rb, you can do something like:

`if @file.save
   # update bottle database using data from @file
end`

however, if you want this to be done every time a new file is created, through the view or not, you can add an 
`after_create` callback to your file.rb model.  If you want it to be done every time after it's saved, you can do an `after_save` callback.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I am new to ROR so every thing at this point is helpful. The problem I am having is how to integrate the importing steps inside of the files_controller. I  followed the procedure in the "Importing Excel" Railscast tutorial where I create an import method in my bottles controller and model to be able to open the excel file within the bottle model and then import it into the bottle database. So in theory I can call the import method of my bottle model in the file controller after if.save in the create action?

Comment: yes that should work.  When the controller does 
`if @file.save`

that is saving the file. to the database.  If it saves correctly it will return true, and go into the block following the if statement. so you can then call

`Bottle.create_from_file(@file)` 

Or whatever your create from file function is for bottle and that will do it.

Comment: Okay, so if I created a class method in bottles.rb called, 'def self.import(file_url)'. So in my filecontroller.rb, after save, I tried calling 'Bottle.import(params[:file_url])' after the 'if.save' but I get an error in the bottles.rb model saying that file_url is nil. The attribute File_url is where the excel file is uploaded to (Using CarrierWave) in the file index view. However, the excel file is not being transferred over. So, by following your advise, I could do something like, Bottle.import(@file.file_url) after the if '@file.save'? I appreciate your help! Just a little overwhelmed.=]

Comment: looks like you got it working above and answered your own question there :)

Answer (score 0):

Okay After if`@file.save`

I added `Bottle.import(@file.file_url.path)`

And in the `bottle.rb` model, I changed

```
spreadsheet =  Roo::Excel.new(file_url.path, packed: nil,file_warning: :ignore)
```

to

```
spreadsheet =  Roo::Excel.new(file_url, packed: nil,file_warning: :ignore)
```

AND BOOM!